# Elasticsearch Aggregation - Unable to perform aggregation to object

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a mapping with an inner object as follows:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_all": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "properties": {
            "foo": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "address": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "address": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "city": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try the following aggregation it does not return any data:

```
post data:*/foo/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "address.city"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to put field *city* or *address.city*, aggregation returns zero but if i put *foo.address.city* it is then when i get the correct respond by elasticsearch. This also affects kibana behavior

Any ideas why this is happening? I saw there is a [mapping refactoring](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring) that might affects this. I use elasticsearch version *1.7.1*

To add on this if, I use the relative path in a search query as follows it works normally:

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "address.city": "london"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is there a field name called foo and a index type called foo ?

Comment: no this is a simplified example I have added for the purposes of the question

Comment: Sorry typo in my question - "Is there a field name called foo and a index type called foo"

Comment: yes I have the name of a type the same with the name of a field that is correct do you think that this is causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems its this same [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7411).
This is seen when the type name and field name is same.

Comment: so as of issue https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8870 it seems that it should be expected at version 2.0.0?